# Counting Multiple Factors in R

Tags: r

I conducted a simple survey with two conditions and ten questions, all answered by "yes" or "no." In R I have a data frame with columns Participant ID, Condition (1 or 2, as factors), and 10 columns for each question (with 1 or 2 for "yes" or "no" as factors). I want a count of the frequencies of "yes" or "no" for each participant, so I can run a chi square test by condition. However I cannot figure out how to get it to give me the count of "yes" and "no" by participant.

I basically want to do tapply(data$question1, data$Participant, count), but not only on "question1" but on all 10 questions. How do I do this so I can run a chi square?

Answer (score 0):

You're close...Try something like this:

```
data(swiss)
swiss$Fertility <- ifelse(swiss$Fertility < mean(swiss$Fertility), "yes", "no")
apply(swiss[,2:6], 2, FUN = function(x) tapply(x, swiss$Fertility, NROW))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `table`

```
table(df1[1][row(df1[-1])], unlist(df1[-1]))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(ParticipantID= 1:5, matrix(sample(c('yes', 
          'no'), 5*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=10))
```